# Does the saving throw for a Solar's Slaying Longbow occur before or after the damage roll?

Tags: dnd-5e, attack, saving-throw

A [Solar's](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/solar) *Slaying Longbow* attack is unique in that it has the ability to instantly kill an opponent who has 100 hit points or less if they fail a constitution saving throw:

> **Slaying Longbow.** *Ranged Weapon Attack:* +13 to hit, range 150/600 ft., one target. Hit: 15 (2d8 + 6) piercing damage plus 27 (6d8) radiant damage. If the target is a creature that has 100 hit points or fewer, it must succeed on a DC 15 Constitution saving throw or die.

Assuming the attack hits, are you supposed to roll and apply the weapon damage damage, and then check if the creature meets the hit point threshold? Or, do you check if the creature meets the hit point threshold and then apply the weapon damage afterward?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When reading the action block from left to right it follows this order:

1. Target one item. Creature, object, building, whatever they are looking for. Assume creature for this scenario.
2. Hit deals 2d8+6 piercing damage and 6d8 radiant damage.
3. Conditional if target was hit is a creature. DC 15 con save or die if they have 100 or fewer HP.

So they take the damage then make the constitution save. Proving it is a good idea not to make a Solar mad enough to attack you.

Comment: Also confirmed by Crawford: ["Slaying Longbow sequence: 1. Hit 2. Deal damage (apply any resistance) 3. Make saving throw if the target has hit points ≤ 100"](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/816456912917000192)